# Please explain the output of the ls -all command

Tags: ls

This is one of the many similar lines from the output from ls -all

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 subhrcho dba   25 Dec  6 01:36 beam-server.jpr -> .ade_path/beam-server.jpr
```

What does the above signify ? I am specially interested in `.ade_path` ? What does the dot(.) signify here ?

Comment: remember there is no `-all` option. It is either `--all`, which is the same as `-a` or `-a -l -l` which can be shortened to -all. What you are doing is the latter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the fields in ls -al output mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `beam-server.jpr` is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `.ade_path/beam-server.jpr`. This is also what the `l` stands for in the file's permissions.

File and directory names prefixed with a full stop (`.`) are [hidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) and not normally listed by `ls` unless the `-a` or `--all` arguments are passed.

Comment: Specifying the `-l` option twice does nothing to show hidden files.

Comment: @Amazed how can i see the contents of .ade_path ?

Comment: @Geek `cd .ade_path;ls`