# Why is there a minor number in /dev for directories such as pts?

Tags: files, directory, ls

This is a part of `/dev` in CentOS 6.6. What is the meaning of the minor number for directories like `.`, `..` , `bsg`, `block` and `...` ?

```
drwxr-xr-x. 18 root root        3800 Jul  3 06:00 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 21 root root        4096 Jul  3 05:59 ..
crw-rw----.  1 root video    10, 175 Jul  3 05:59 agpgart
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root         620 Jul  3 05:59 block
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root          80 Jul  3 05:59 bsg
crw-------.  1 root root     10, 234 Jul  3 05:59 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root          60 Jul  3 05:59 bus
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root           3 Jul  3 05:59 cdrom1 -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root           3 Jul  3 05:59 cdrw1 -> sr0
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root        3000 Jul  3 06:00 char
```

Answer (score 5):

For files which are not device that is not the minor number but the size in bytes.

The size of a directory depends on which filesystem is used, and how many entries (i.e. files or subdirectories) are in it.

Comment: So, how can i find the size of character device and block device files?

Comment: @ali the device files are zero size. The information required is stored in the directory entry

Comment: @pqnet Actually the inode. (Depends on filesystem of course; IIRC FAT32 has no inodes, but then again it has no device files either)

Answer (score 3):

Those are not minor numbers (as they are for the device nodes). [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean) explains each field in turn.