# Unable to understand the output of /devices/pseudo

Tags: solaris

When I `ls -al /devices/pseudo`, I see one entry which I’m not able to understand.

```
crw—w——  1 8888 tty 24,  58. Apr 11 2016 pts@0:58
```

Can someone please explain each column for me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't read that directly like you are trying.
That is going to require some lowlevel programming.
If you are trying to write a "key copy" this isn't the correct way of going about it.
Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the fields in ls -al output mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean)

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can try is to run a command like `tail`:

```
tail -f /dev/ttys000

then in another terminal type 
#echo hello >> /dev/ttys000
```

and you will see it print out.

As special chars get involved here... it is going to goof your screen, though.