# creating hard links Linux question

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, ls, hard-link

From the book *The Linux Command Line* by William Shotts, page 33:

> So now we have four instances of the file fun. Let's take a look at
> our playground directory.
>
> ```
> [me@linuxbox playground]$ ls -1
> total 16
> drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 2018-01-14 16:17 dir1
> drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 2018-01-14 16:17 dir2
> -rw-r--r-- 4 me me 1650 2018-01-10 16:33 fun
> -rw-r--r-- 4 me me 1650 2018-01-10 16:33 fun-hard
> ```

Total 16? I can’t see 16 files

Could you explain what this description means exactly:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 2018-01-14 16:17 dir1
```

What does this letters means: `drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096`?

Why “me me”?

> One thing we notice is that both the second fields in the listings for
> fun and fun-hard contain a 4, which is the number of hard links that
> now exist for the file.

Why he’s calling second fields?

Contain a 4?? I’m only seeing one file:
`-rw-r--r-- 4 me me 1650 2018-01-10 16:33 fun`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Unix.SE! I can only answer to some of your questions.  In `drwxrwxr-x` the beginning `d` means that this line refers to a directory: in fact, `dir1` and `dir2` are directories. The first `me` is the username of the author in his Linux system; the second `me` is his group. The "fields" are groups of characters, separated by spaces: `-rw-r--r--` is the *first* field, `4` is the *second* field, `me` is the *third* field and so on. Please, search Google for the output of the `ls` command: try [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-list-files-in-linux-using-the-ls-command/).

Comment: `ls -1` won't have given you that output. I think you intended `ls -l`. Did you copy this from the book, or are you actually trying the examples on your own machine? You _really_ need to be able to follow along and try stuff out yourself

Comment: Also: [What do the fields in ls -al output mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103114/70524)

Answer (score 0):

To address one of your questions, `total 16` on the first line of output for `ls -l` indicates that the files in that directory use 16 blocks of disk space, not that there are 16 files.  A block is by default 1024 bytes, so 16384 bytes are allocated for the contents of the directory `playground`.

A verbose explanation of `ls` options and output can be found by executing `info '(coreutils) ls invocation` on the system where you are testing the things you are reading about.  As noted in a comment on your question, with a book like this, it is important to experiment with the commands as they are introduced, and not just read the text.

Comment: The given info command assumes a) info is installed, b) ls is from GNU coreutils - Unix-like systems use man as the command to access system manual/help. Neither assumption could be made based on the question.