# Hard link linux

Tags: command-line

The Linux Command Line

William Shotts

Page 33

```
[me@linuxbox playground] $ ls -1   
total 16    
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 2018-01-14 16:17 dir1
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 2018-01-14 16:17 dir2
-rw-r—r— 4 me me 1650 2018-01-10 16:33 fun
-rw-r—r— 4 me me 1650 2018-01-10 16:33 fun-hard
```

One thing we notice is that both the second fields in the listings for fun
and fun-hard contain a 4, which is the number of hard links that now exist for
the file. Remember that a file will always have at least one link because the
file's name is created by a link.

Please explain this better:

fun and fun-hard contain 4 hard links?dir1 and dir2 contain 2 hard links?

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 2018-01-14 16:17 dir1
```

How can this  data file contain 2 hard links ?

Remember that a file will always have at least one link because the
file's name is created by a link.

I can’t understand this

Comment: Please use [code block]s to format command output

Comment: Please DO NOT post [the same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/757005/100397) twice. Instead, edit your first one.

Answer (score 1):

When you `mkdir dir1`, it creates the directory and populates it with `.` which refers to current directory in `dir1`.  So, there are two links: `dir1` in the directory where you created `dir1` and `.` inside `dir1`.

Answer (score 1):

> Please explain this better:
> fun and fun-hard contain 4 hard links?dir1 and dir2 contain 2 hard links?

The book's remark, "which is the number of hard links that now exist for the file", hints that the multiple links are a result of several consecutive lessons in the book, showing how to create hard links.  So the book's larger context will explain why there are 4 of them, and this remark mentions why a file will always show at least one hard link.

Explanations for the book's examples and descriptions are best looked-for in the book, especially one that's written as a learning guide that begins with basic concepts and progresses to the more sophisticated concepts/examples, like this one.

As other answers mentioned, a directory (which is different from a file) begins life with two hard links instead of one.